# cannot send crash report after setting up react native crashlytics for android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I feel like I have tried every possible combination of ways to report a crash on the firebase crashlytics console for the android side of my react-native application.

I have followed the rnfirebase setup instructions and triple checked that everything is where it should be: https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/android-setup

I have read in several forums that the app needs to be run in 'release' mode for the crash to be reported and then the app must be closed and opened once again for the report to be sent, I have done this multiple times:

firstly i've tried:
./gradlew installRelease

secondly I tried a method recommended in a github issue forum:
./gradlew assembleRelease
adb install ./app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

both methods ran on my emulator and I was able to use the crashlytics().crash() method to cause a crash, alas nothing appears in the console.

I have also added this into a firebase.json file in the root of my project like the docs explain:

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true
  }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated as I really don't know where the issue lies.

PS. I have registered my app with the FB console and enabled crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

in firebase.json

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "crashlytics_disable_auto_disabler": true,
    "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true
  }
}
```

make sure that crashanalytics sdk is installed/initialised
follow: https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/android-setup

Comment: I'll give this a try! let's see if it helps

Comment: I've tried crashing the app in both debug and release variants, nothing has shown up yet but i'll check back tomorrow and give an update

Comment: this didn't work for me, nothing has shown up in the console yet even though the app does crash when calling the crashlytics().crash() method